# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product, user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I'm working in a application where you can vote for a product and from the New action of my vote view I get this error:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in VotesController#create
>
> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product, user

I make a test on rails console and it works. So I don't know what it's going on.

Here are the models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :votes
  has_many :users, :through => :votes
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300" }

  before_save { |product| product.title = title.titlecase }

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :photo, :attachment_presence => true

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes
    has_many :products, :through => :votes
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
      end
    end
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the vote controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /votes
  # GET /votes.json
  def index
    @votes = Vote.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @votes }
    end
  end

  # GET /votes/1
  # GET /votes/1.json
  def show
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @vote }
    end
  end

  # GET /votes/new
  # GET /votes/new.json
  def new
    @vote = Vote.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @vote }
    end
  end

  # GET /votes/1/edit
  def edit
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /votes
  # POST /votes.json
  def create
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @vote, notice: 'Vote was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @vote, status: :created, location: @vote }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /votes/1
  # PUT /votes/1.json
  def update
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.update_attributes(params[:vote])
        format.html { redirect_to @vote, notice: 'Vote was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /votes/1
  # DELETE /votes/1.json
  def destroy
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
    @vote.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to votes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the new vote view

```
<%= form_for(@vote) do |f| %>
  <% if @vote.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@vote.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this vote from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @vote.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :product %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Please I really need your help to solve this issues, it was very difficult to find a tutorial with has_many :through that include the complete MVC example, I think my problem is on the view, but I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: `:product` and `:user` are not properties of the `Vote` model, they are relations. Instead, you need to use `:product_id` and `:user_id` in the `votes/_form` view. There are ways to get select boxes and such for the relations, but try this first.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I just tried and I still get the same error in the form_for I change  <%= f.text_field :product %> by  <%= f.text_field :product_id %> and <%= f.text_field :user %> by <%= f.text_field :user_id %>

Comment: did you do the same for `f.label :product` and `f.label :user`?

Comment: You should get a `parameters` read out on the error page that comes up. Can you tell me what that says?

Comment: Sure. {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"u8Hs85OAZiC5LTEqL4Kwz5uXHXujmuvrk1ZRoQiU2JQ=",
 "vote"=>{"product"=>"1",
 "user"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Vote"}

Comment: it seems like your view did not update. Try restarting your rails server and make sure all of your changes have been saved.

Answer (score 1):

That error message tells you everything you need to know if you look closely at it.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in VotesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product, user
```

you may not be familiar with the term "mass-assignment".  its the assignment of 1 or more of an objects attributes at the time of creation.  i.e. `in VotesController#create`.
when unprotected, mass-assignment opens you up to hackers assigning values to any and all of an objects attributes in your site's forms wether you meant to give access or not.

thats where `attar_accessible` comes in. it forces you to be explicit about what attributes of a model your users should have access to. any not passed as symbols into the macro will be `protected attributes` as in `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product, user`.

the scaffolding set `attr_accessible :product_id, :user_id` when it created your model but it didnt know you were going to assign these with objects rather than id values.

you can fix this one of 2 ways.

change your form so that the hash-like `params` variable assigns like this

```
params[vote][product_id]
```

or change your model like

```
attr_accessible :product, :user
```